# Upgrading a server vs fresh install

Tags: server, upgrade

I have an old VM which some years ago I upgraded from Ubuntu 14 LTS to 16. Now I've upgraded it to 18. My question is, can I assume that this installation is almost 100% identical to a freshly installed Ubuntu 18 LTS regarding the distribution, kernel, configurations etc?

In other words, should I be upgrading servers or should I be rebuilding fresh ones?

Comment: No. There are differences.

Comment: There was no Ubuntu Core 14; but if you for example upgrade a Ubuntu Core 16 system to Ubuntu Core 18; only the base system itself upgrades; no application packages changed - which is a *huge* difference between the 16 or *year* based products to the far more widely used *year.month* systems (ie. a 16 to 18 upgrade differs greatly to a 16.04 upgrade to 20.04).  Ubuntu has used *year* format releases with their 10 year life span to highlight different products to the more common *year.month* products since 2016..  ie. 16 != 16.04

Comment: The release notes generally highlight what the differences are, and if you're impacted by those changes; how to mitigate the changes/differences.  eg. locations where specific files may differ on a new install, where as upgraded installs may keep using the older location; these vary on release-to-release upgrade & are documented in release notes (upgrade section).

Comment: Depending on how good you are at housecleaning, you may have lots of cruft. Most log files do get cycled out after so many, but things just accumulate.

Comment: My system is a *release-upgraded* one that's been many times, and as such many things differ over a clean install of the release my system is.  If you read the *release-notes* for each of the upgrades; the changes are listed; some of which are changed during *release-upgrade* others are not. For example some *config* files of my system match the older releases which is a different location to a *clean* install of the same release. Both work; my *release-upgraded* system follows older rules to a *new* install - these differences being documented & vary on releases involved. Read the doco!

Comment: My ^ prior comment assumes *year.month* systems though & no the *year* products you mention.  There is far less change in the *year* products as few things change during upgrades.  On the *year.month* systems all applications get upgraded; where as with *year* systems only the base-OS gets upgraded; meaning you can upgrade from 16 to 18 to 20 with no application changes on a Ubuntu Core system; where as 16.04 to 18.04 will incur changes; as again 18.04 to 20.04 - but change will vary on packages installed.  Don't forget 16 & 16.04 are different products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be some differences, but most folks won't notice those differences in normal use.

Whether or not to release-upgrade or to install anew depends upon your preferences and needs. Choose the path that makes you most comfortable.

Since you are running a Virtual Machine, you have a unique opportunity to try *both* paths before deciding which version to keep.